# What is the best way to study graduate level mathematics?

Tags: measure-theory, soft-question, self-learning, advice

I am studying a 400/500 level measure theory math book on my own.
Right now, when I read it I try to read the proposition then the following proof. And then try to do the exercises on my own. 
I wonder if I should change it to:-
1. read the proposition
2. try to prove it on my own.
3. If I could not then proceed to read the proof from the book.
4. Do the exercises.

Or should I stick with everything above minus step 2. It can save me some time but I wonder if that is what good mathematics students do?

Any feedback from your experience would be appreciated.

Best,

Comment: There's no "should" about this. You want a mix, depending on your learning style and what works for you. Consider working with several books at once. Seeing multiple versions of theorems and proofs might help you triangulate on concepts.

Comment: What book are you using?  Your success on step 2 will vary a lot, I think, depending on the book.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Am using Robert Ash Probability and Measure Theory. Is there any more intuitive complement book that you would suggest?

Comment: I think there are two different modes of learning math, and both are vital but they are somewhat at odds with each other. Mode 1: Trying to grok the proofs and generally understand the material as deeply as possible. This is a slow process. Mode 2: Learning in a "big picture first" style. You look at a map of the world before you commit yourself to learning your way around a particular city. You get a high level, coarse picture of how a subject fits together before learning proofs in detail. Balancing these two modes is a difficult question of calibration / hyperparameter tuning.

Comment: I think it is good practice to think about a proposition a bit before reading the proof.  You don't always have to prove it yourself, but putting yourself in the problem-solving mindset very much aids in an intuitive understanding of the proof when you do read it.  Think about how your attempt at a proof might start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With regards to learning from proofs provided in a textbook, it may be very beneficial to

- (step 1) mentally try to guess how a proof is going to substantiate its claim
- (step 2) read the textbook-proof
- (step 3) write a personalized proof while having access to the textbook-proof emphasizing clarity
- (step 4) write a personalized proof while having access to the textbook-proof emphasizing brevity
- (step 5) write a formal proof without having access to the textbook-proof.

Here "formal" means "able to be understood by other mathematicians---most importantly your instructor."